# grunt bower-install into the php file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I have the following problem:

I am trying add routes js files in php.
In a html file works perfectly.

Why not work in a php file?

Try:

```
grunt bower-install
```

Error:

```
Verifying property bower-install.app.src exists in config...OK
Reading bower.json...OK
Parsing bower.json...OK
Warning: Cannot read property 'block' of undefined Use --force to continue.
```

The code:

```
bower: {
      dev: {
        dest: './components'
      },
    },
    'bower-install': {
      app: {
        src: ['template.php']
      },
    },
  }
```

There is a issue since a week ago, but no response there.
https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/issues/33

Comment: You should open an issue on the related Github repository after checking this issue is not already reported.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias there are a issue in https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/issues/33

Comment: Doesn't seems so bad. Looks like wiredep is looking at file extension and just don't process `.php`. It should be pretty easy to send a PR and fixing the issue yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like says @SimonBoudrias. You have to go to the following file path:

```
node_modules/grunt-bower-install/node_modules/wiredep/lib/inject-dependencies.js
```

Add to fileTypesDefaults object, the object **php**

```
var fileTypesDefault = {
  html: {
    block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
    detect: {
      js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
      css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
    },
    replace: {
      js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>',
      css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
    }
  }, php: {
    block: /(([\s\t]*)<!--\s*bower:*(\S*)\s*-->)(\n|\r|.)*?(<!--\s*endbower\s*-->)/gi,
    detect: {
      js: /<script.*src=['"](.+)['"]>/gi,
      css: /<link.*href=['"](.+)['"]/gi
    },
    replace: {
      js: '<script src="{{filePath}}"></script>',
      css: '<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{filePath}}" />'
    }
  },

  yaml: {
    block: /(([\s\t]*)#\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(#\s*endbower)/gi,
    detect: {
      js: /-\s(.+)/gi,
      css: /-\s(.+)/gi
    },
    replace: {
      js: '- {{filePath}}',
      css: '- {{filePath}}'
    }
  }
};
```

A regards

Comment: This can also be passed in through your `Gruntfile`: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install#getting-started - you would just need to pass in the PHP portion of the above object ( `fileTypes: { php: { /* ... */ } }`

I think I should probably just default unrecognized file extentions to use the HTML configuration.